# Ajax success not setting value of variable

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a simple ajax call on one of my views.

```
var countAnchors;

$.ajax({
    url: countUrl,
    method: "GET",
    data: @Model.InitialTrainingId,
    success: function (result) {
        console.log("result: ",result);
        countAnchors = result;
    },
    error: function (jqXHR) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
        alert("There was a problem");
    }
});

console.log("countAnchors: ",countAnchors);
```

When I run this, in the console I am seeing:

[image]

Why isn't `countAnchors` being assigned the value in the success function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a `function` ,so whenever response comes you can assign value to your `variable` like below:

```
var countAnchors=null;

  function result(r){
    countAnchors= r;//assigning value return
   console.log("countAnchors: ",countAnchors);
  }

    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "readString.php",  
        data: { 'fn': filename },      
        success: function(response){
            result(response); //calling function
        },
       error: function (jqXHR) {
       console.log(jqXHR);
       alert("There was a problem");
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your log entries are giving you a hint.

Unless you specify otherwise, ajax calls will run asynchronously.

In this case, you are seeing in the log that your logging of the value of countAnchors happens before the ajax call has completed.  Just because it was written earlier in the script block doesn't mean (in this case) that it's finished before the next part of the script block is executed.

I bet this will give you a value, and will return the two lines to the console log in the expected order:

```
var countAnchors;

$.ajax({
    url: countUrl,
    method: "GET",
    data: @Model.InitialTrainingId,
    success: function (result) {
        console.log("result: ",result);
        countAnchors = result;
        console.log("countAnchors: ",countAnchors);
        doSomething();
    },
    error: function (jqXHR) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
        alert("There was a problem");
    }
});

function doSomething()
{
    alert('countAnchors: ' + countAnchors);
}
```

EDIT:  If you need to *do* something with the value of countAnchors, create a new javascript function and call it from the success function after countAnchors is set.

Answer (score 0):

Because

```
console.log("countAnchors: ",countAnchors);
```

run before success function and at this time 'countAnchors' is still undefined

Comment: So, how do I know if `countAnchors` is being assigned the correct value?  How do I test that?

Comment: uhmm..you can check it right after console.log("result: ",result) I guess

Comment: But the problem is that I am performing conditional statements based on the value of `countAnchors` outside of the ajax call that I posted in my question.  So, if it doesn't have the correct value and only has `undefined`, then my conditional statements won't work as expected

Comment: You have to do it inside 'success'